# Obtain list of directories in hierarchy, which contain only symbolical links

Tags: solaris, symlink, tcsh

I'm aware of various tools available to obtain a list of directories in hierarchy, which contain only symbolical links, but I am not proficient enough to invent a solution myself.

Personally, I will have to use tcsh to do this.

Another problem I have is how to do the same, but only list directories containing at least one symbolic link and at least one other file.

Comment: I can use find and grep, but I'm on Solaris 10 iirc, and thus some options for those may be unavailable.

Comment: At first I wanted to do something with pipes, but then I thought that it won't be easy if I have to generate two streams. I thought this could be done somehow by generating two or more lists of directories and doing set algebra with them. There are tools for that if the input is sorted. But what if I ever want to copy core solution into problem with ordered input? I can't sort the input then, or at least I would need to be able to restore the original order before finally outputting. I was thinking about pipes, but I also thought about files. But then, I don't know if there is a smart way to

Comment: create temporary files. What if my script is ever used concurrently? How do I generate filenames and share them between pieces of the script? I guess that's actually possible... But then, I am wondering if I can create actual lists from find results and basically write a sane piece of code as in usual programming languages?

Comment: So you have to solve a problem you're not qualified to solve, and you're trying to learn scripting basics on [unix.se]?

Comment: No, I'm trying to give you a chance to seem smart. You're welcome.

Comment: Why do you have to use `tcsh`? Even if you use `tcsh` as your interactive shell, you don't have to use the same shell for a script.

Comment: well, if it could be done in a oneliner, i'd rather do it in tcsh, but I guess you're right

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it, with `sh` and GNU `find`, and assuming filenames don't have embedded newlines:

```sh
#! /bin/sh
find /path/to/dir -type d -links 2 | \
    while read -r d; do
        found=0
        for f in "$d"/*; do
            if [ ! -h "$f" ]; then continue 2; fi
            found=1
        done
        if [ x$found = x1 ]; then printf '%s\n' "$d"; fi
    done
```

Problems with this approach:

- not `tcsh`
- it can be fooled by files starting with a dot.

**Edit:** with `python`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

for topdir in sys.argv:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(topdir):
        if not dirs and files:
            if all(os.path.islink(os.path.join(root, f)) for f in files):
                print os.path.join(root)
```

Problem with this approach: `python` may not be installed.

Comment: Note that -P is redundant here. If you remove it, that becomes portable to the OP's solaris 10. `read -r` will not work with Solaris 10 `/bin/sh` (which is a Bourne shell). The standard `sh` is `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` on Solaris. Also note that `read -r d` won't work with filenames ending in space or containing newline characters

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas True, it's probably easier / more portable to do this in Python or Perl.

Answer (score 1):

directories with only symlinks will be leaves in the directory tree as if not they would contain directories and thus non-symlinks.

On Solaris, at least for UFS and ZFS file systems, you should be able to search for directories with fewer than 3 links for that.

```
find . -type d -links -3 -exec sh -c 'ls -Anq "$0" | awk "NR==1{next};/^[^l]/{exit 1};END{if (NR<2) {exit 1}}"' {} \; -print
```

For directories with at least one symlink and one non-symlinks, you'd need to check every dir:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'ls -Anq "$0" | awk "NR==1{next};/^[^l]/{nonlink++};/^l/{link++}; END{exit !(link&&nonlink)}"' {} \; -print
```